# Bootstrap bug or browser rendering issue on mobile devices?

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

Had this problem minutes ago in Yii, but anyway, its bootstrap (3.2) related:

```
<div class="row col-xs-12">
    <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'email', array('size' => 60, 'maxlength' => 255, "class" => "form-control input-lg", "placeholder" => "Your E-mail")); ?>
    // or, in plain html:
    <input class="form-control input-lg" name="email" size="60" maxlength="255" placeholder="Your E-Mail">
</div>
```

I tested it on iPhone, Android - cannot click on input box
Yesterday BS 3.3 released but still the same problem

Anyone had similar issue ?

Answer (score 0):

**And here is the solution:**
It seems that adding col-xs-12 (col-md-X, col-sm-X, no matter) is the problem, after removing it the "layer" created over input control dissapeared.

Answer (score 0):

`class="row col-xs-12"` is invalid. You cannot put `row` and `col-*` on the same element.
See https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki/E005

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
<div class="row">





    <div class=" col-xs-12">
Code goes here
</div>
</div>
```